# Programmatically disabling the screen blanker on X11

Tags: c, x11

Is there a way to programmatically disable the screen blanker on X11? For example, a presentation application might want to turn off the screen blanker while showing its slides in fullscreen mode to prevent the screen blanker from coming to the front because there has been no user activity for some time. Is that possible or does it have to be disabled manually?

Comment: Yes, that thread pretty much tells me what I want to know. Thread can be closed...